# send complex objects as post php java

Tags: php, android, http, post

Is it possible to send all my contact numbers via post to php from my class inside eclipse ? or post is only limited to primitive types and I have to find work arounds to send them as a String ?

Comment: send as xml or json string

Comment: Sending them as Json or XML be good Choice but if u really need to send Contact you  can write your contact to file using CSV and upload it to server in post request ie there ae open CSV parser for both end , it is up to your convenience .

Answer (score 0):

I would propose:
send them as [Json](http://www.json.org/) in the Post request, befor start, have a look at the [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) Project and keep in mind to set the content to application -> json. good luck